# Quantum Fisher Information for finding distance between two states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

If we have two points at $x$ and $x'$ at distance d that have entanglement bond. At each point we consider some state let say coherent states $\psi(\mu,x)$ and $\psi(\mu,x')$. Can we measure the distance between these states with the help of Quantum Fisher Information?

Comment: States cannot be entangled with each other. Systems can.

Comment: the Fisher is closely related to the Bures metric, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fisher_information, so sure, it "measures distances" between states (sort of: it's a metric, so you'd have to use the corresponding distance). However, the relation between this and "multipartite entanglement" is not clear in your question. Can you link the references you're thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well...the canonical source on this is

> Braunstein SL, Caves CM. Statistical distance and the geometry of
> quantum states. Physical Review Letters. 1994 May 30;72(22):3439

although it is somewhat advanced and not terribly self-contained (as are most research papers in PRL) so I do not find it super useful.  A more recent view

> Sidhu JS, Kok P. Geometric perspective on quantum parameter estimation. AVS Quantum Science. 2020 Feb 11;2(1):014701.

might also be difficult but at least it integrates in a more digestible way a lot of the notions developed in the last 25years on this topic.  It is IMO a better starting point that B&C.  Sidhu & Kok include in Sec. IV C some references to various distance measures, and this could be a good starting point.